# Start activity from service using timer

Tags: android, android-activity, alarmmanager

I want to call my main Activity from service after every 10 min. How do I do this?

I tried using `AlarmManager`. I triggered `MyAppReceiver` using the following code:

```
private void setNextSchedule()
{
     AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,new Intent(this,     MyAppReciever.class), 0);
     long duration = 20000;
     am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
     SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), duration, pi);
}
```

and called it in `onStartCommand()` of service, but it's not working.

```
public class MyAppReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(context,"in myAppreceiver",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

In Manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".MyAppReciever" />
```

Comment: Show us your `MyAppReceiver` class and how you defined it in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: I have edited. Plz check

Comment: I still don't see your Manifest file

Comment: Where is your <receiver> in manifest edit the whole manifest? Make sure that it is inside the <application>.

Comment: yes it is inside <application>  <receiver android:name=".MyAppReceiver"/>